# JAXB / xjc generated Exception classes are not Throwable

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, wsdl, xjc

I am using jaxb-xjc (version 2.2.4-1, in a Gradle task) to generate Java classes from wsdl (to be used as a web service client).

According to wsdl documentation, some of the endpoints may throw custom exceptions.

The generated code looks fine, except for one detail: The generated exception classes do not extend Throwable (or any other class that would extend it). WSDL seems to be ok, as there is a fault element named in these endpoints (example):

```
<wsdl:fault name="IdentityNotFoundException" message="work_v2:IdentityNotFoundException"/>
```

Is there a way to configure xjc to make these custom Exception classes to be "real" exception classes? Current Gradle/xjc task configuration is:

```
            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: "src/main/resources/wsdl/workService_v2.wsdl",
                package: "workService.generated") {
            arg(value: "-wsdl")
            produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured a workaround for this:

Instead of using xjc, I used another generator instead: [wsdl2java](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java)

And surprise - The newly generated classes now extend Exception class! The Gradle settings used for wsdl2java were according to the example in its Github page.